# Why is a shell within a docker container showing dmesg content from the host?

Tags: docker, containers, privileges, elevated-privileges

I have a docker container running Debian jessie on Ubuntu yakkety.

When within the docker (connected via `ssh` for instance) I am isolated from the host (which is expected). I however realized that `dmesg` shows me the messages for the host and not for the container. **How can it have access to information of its host?**

The configuration of the docker container is not special (except that it uses a specific bridge, different from `docker0`), in particular it does not run in any privileged mode (`"Privileged": false` below):

```
root@srv ~# docker inspect minecraft-1-8
[
    {
        "Id": "748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e",
        "Created": "2016-12-01T15:35:05.287672787Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/supervisord",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 28650,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-12-15T18:37:08.409564695Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2016-12-15T18:37:07.457274028Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:78a2f88d47e29523503c2196ed2faaa3d1039d948d73987edc03b2abd338595d",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e/748cfdfbf3fb5526cb7151cbc0857117af3c7bd8ab9e086c4f2efb897290d66e-json.log",
        "Name": "/minecraft-1-8",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "docker",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/e78ce9dbcedd6974429a4aada8f38913b7d35da41f586f203dd99a568f38b6c3/root",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/e8422e4707d95db8ea747af2367626cc8bf16e95f8eb05dfad9a63461c9ade86/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/e8422e4707d95db8ea747af2367626cc8bf16e95f8eb05dfad9a63461c9ade86/upper",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/e8422e4707d95db8ea747af2367626cc8bf16e95f8eb05dfad9a63461c9ade86/work"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "minecraft-1-8",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/usr/bin/supervisord"
            ],
            "Image": "minecraft",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "cf411634babad31138ab4572b9cd7306f74a54dd1baf4cd8d7706d7e7020c594",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cf411634baba",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "docker": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.200.0.100"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "748cfdfbf3fb"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "7b20560b36032d36ffe6c0ebece6b4408355d207f4e203a2957b0434ee0afdc1",
                    "EndpointID": "9fa4fc914dfe76022ce0db02e48a7e7c85c57bc2a15b0b3e5d81b1f24d95f376",
                    "Gateway": "10.200.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "10.200.0.100",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:c8:00:64"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Show your `docker run` command

Comment: @user2915097: I `start` an existing container created with `docker create --network docker --ip 10.200.0.100 --name=minecraft-1-8 -h minecraft-1-8 base`, where `base` is a debian yakkety image.

Comment: This was [raised as security concern](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37897), and [fixed in latest version](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37929).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most distro's [`dmesg`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmesg) is not a privileged command. Any user can use the [klogctl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/klogctl) interface to read the kernel ring buffer.

```
$ id
uid=1001(matt) gid=1001(matt) groups=1001(matt)
$ dmesg | head -1
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

But can't do anything beyond read

```
$ dmesg -C
dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted
```

Which extends to Docker

```
$ sudo docker run debian dmesg | head -1
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
$ sudo docker run debian dmesg -C
dmesg: klogctl failed: Operation not permitted
```

#### Restricting access

You can restrict read access down to root users and those with the CAP_SYSLOG or CAP_SYS_ADMIN [capabilities](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) via `/proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict`.

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict
```

Then you should be getting a permission denied message:

```
$ docker run ubuntu:yakkety dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Running a container in privileged mode will then regain access to the hosts kernel ring buffer

```
$ docker run --privileged ubuntu:yakkety dmesg
[146902.131915] br-fa26f1dc96a1: port 3(veth80d3d5d) entered disabled state
...
```

Use sysctl to configure `kernel.dmesg_restrict=1` if you need it permanently.

#### Namespacing

As to why the kernel log doesn't have name spacing like other kernel areas, I think the answer is "it's difficult". There's more detail than you'd care to know in this 2012 [Stepping closer to practical containers: "syslog" namespaces LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/527342/) post. I can't see any reference's to it getting any further than proposed patches: https://lwn.net/Articles/562389/ https://lwn.net/Articles/561271/. As you can see in this [recent netfilter patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/616057/), they have a work around to allow rules in a container name space to use the global log.

Comment: Thank you Matt. My concern was about the third point of your answer - I do not care about who can see (and do what) within the container **for the container data**. The ability to see the host logs is very annoying as these logs may hold information not intended for the (segregated and unprivileged) docker instance.

Comment: @WoJ yeah probably best to just disable non privileged access.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was already the case? (looking at the `inspect` output)

Comment: ...to the klogctl read functions via `kernel.dmesg_restrict=1`

Comment: Wondering why `dmesg_restrict` is set to 0 by default? People don't think it sensitive?

Comment: @FranklinYu it's a point of contention. See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2020-June/041063.html for a proposal to change it in Ubuntu 20.10 and https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-May/033240.html for historical context from 2011.